# Get all hashtags using regular expressions

Tags: r, regex

I'm studying the recent hashtag `#BalanceTonPorc` in one of my classes. I'm trying to get all the occurrences of this hashtag appearing in tweets, but of course nobody uses the same format.

Some people use `#BalanceTonPorc`, some `#balancetonporc`, and son on and so forth.

Using `gsub`, I've so far done this :

```
df$hashtags <- gsub(".alance.on.orc", "BalanceTonPorc", df$hashtags)
```

Which does what I want, and all variations of this hashtag are stored under the same one. But there are A LOT of other variations. Some people used `#BalanceTonPorc...` or `#BalanceTonPorc.`

Is there a way to have a RegEx that says I want everything that contains `.alance.on.orc` with every character possible after the hashtag, except `,` (because it separates hashtags)? Here is a screenshot to illustrate what I mean.

[image]

I'm also having another issue, in my frequency table I have twice `#BalanceTonPorc`, so I guess R must consider them to be different. Can you spot the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `[^,]*` to match any char but `,`, 0+ occurrences:

```
gsub(".alance.on.orc[^,]*", "BalanceTonPorc", df$hashtags)
```

Or, to exactly match `balancetonporc`,

```
gsub("balancetonporc[^,]*", "BalanceTonPorc", df$hashtags, ignore.case=TRUE)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gx0b3d/1) and an [R online test](https://ideone.com/LHwJam):

```
x <- c("#balancetonPorc#%$%#$%^","#balancetonporc#%$%, text")
gsub("balancetonporc[^,]*", "BalanceTonPorc", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
# => [1] "#BalanceTonPorc"       "#BalanceTonPorc, text"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I didn't know about `ignore.case`, that's pretty cool ! About my second problem, it was just a problem of space that R didn't show, I solved it using `[^,]*` as well. Have a good day :)

Comment: @ArnaudStephan Also, see more about [**negated character classes**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). A very useful and efficient construct, if you ask me.